# Move a view with OnTouchEvent

Tags: android, touch-event

I Have this code to put a View where I touch in a Screen.
But the View doesn't follow exactly the point where my finger touch.

Can I improve this behavior?

To works like Drag and Drop API but using onTouchEvent?

Thanks for all!

```
 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {

            final float x =   event.getX(); 
            final float y =   event.getY();
            moveView(x, y);
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);

        }

        private void moveView(float x, float y) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
            params.leftMargin = Math.round(x);
            params.topMargin = Math.round(y);   
            selectedView.setLayoutParams(params); 

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try playing around with some offsets to your x and y coordinates.

```
//should be on the order of magnitude of the size of the view
float x_offset= 10;  //Play with this.
float y_offset= 10;  //Play with this.

final float x =   event.getX() + x_offset; 
final float y =   event.getY() + y_offset;

moveView(x, y);
```

Comment: Glad I could help! If you like the answer you should accept it and close the question. I'm a new user so I'd appreciate it too! thanks

Comment: Why do we need these offset and explain it please.

Comment: When you specify where you want to place an object, you are actually specifying where you want to place the top left corner of the object. So, for example, if you want the center of an image where you clicked, you need to add an offset equal to half the height and half the width. All absolute placement that I've ever used works like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
  // These matrices will be used to scale points of the image
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();


// The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform   
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
//private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 5f;
int mode = NONE;

// these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
PointF start = new PointF();
PointF mid = new PointF();
float oldDist = 1f;
float[] lastEvent = null; 
float degrees = 0f;
float newRot = 0f;



OnTouchListener touchAction = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        //perfrom zoom & drag & rotate operations on touch of imageview
        dragZoomRotate((ImageView)v, event);
        return true; 

    }
};

private void dragZoomRotate(ImageView view, MotionEvent event){ 

    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);  

    // Handle touch events here...

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)   
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        start.set(event.getX() , event.getY() );
        mode = DRAG;
        lastEvent = null;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:   // first and second finger down
        oldDist = spacing(event);         
        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        midPoint(mid, event);
        mode = ZOOM;

        lastEvent = new float[4];
        lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
        lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
        lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
        lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
        degrees = rotation(event);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:   // second finger lifted
        mode = NONE;
        lastEvent = null;

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:    
        if (mode == DRAG) { 
            // ...
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);

            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x , event.getY() - start.y );

        }
        else if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount()==2) {
            float newDist = spacing(event);
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            if (newDist > 10f) {              
                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            } 
            if (lastEvent!=null){
                newRot = rotation(event); 
                float r = newRot-degrees;
                matrix.postRotate(r, view.getMeasuredWidth()/2, view.getMeasuredHeight()/2);  
            }
        }
        // 
        break;
    }   

    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
}

private float rotation(MotionEvent event) 
{
    double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
    double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1)); 
    double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
    return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);         
} 




/*     
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Method: spacing Parameters: MotionEvent Returns: float Description:
 * 
 * checks the spacing between the two fingers on touch
 * ----------------------------------------------------
 */

private float spacing(MotionEvent event) 
{
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Method: midPoint Parameters: PointF object, MotionEvent Returns: void
 * Description: calculates the midpoint between the two fingers
 * ------------------------------------------------------------
 */   

private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) 
{
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}
```

Now add the touchAction listener to the view which you want to move...

```
   myImageView.setOnTouchListener(touchAction);
```

Answer (score 0):

try change your layout from RelativeLayout to AbsoluteLayout